# Find matching items in array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-intersect

Absolutely doing my head in here over something that I'm sure is very simple...

I have 2 arrays.

- `$post_cats` which are categories that any given post is in.
- `$ad_cats` which is an array of categories in which ads are placed.

Basically, if a post has in its array of selected categories, a category that matches an item in the array of ad categories, then it must return the matching value/item.

`$post_cats` returns this

```
array(4) {    
  [0]=> array(1) { ["slug"]=> string(6) "energy" }    
  [1]=> array(1) { ["slug"]=> string(6) "global" }  
  [2]=> array(1) { ["slug"]=> string(8) "identify" }  
  [3]=> array(1) { ["slug"]=> string(5) "south" }  
}
```

and `$ad_cats` returns this

```
array(6) {   
  [0]=> array(1) { ["slug"]=> string(5) "north" }  
  [1]=> array(1) { ["slug"]=> string(5) "south" }  
  [2]=> array(1) { ["slug"]=> string(4) "east" }  
  [3]=> array(1) { ["slug"]=> string(4) "west" }  
  [4]=> array(1) { ["slug"]=> string(6) "global" }  
  [5]=> array(1) { ["slug"]=> string(8) "fallback" }  
}
```

The duplicated item there is "south", so in my mind the value of `array_intersect($post_cats, $ad_cats);` should be an array with a single item - "south", correct?

But its returning, what seems like, everything in either of the arrays... I can't for the life of me get it to work..

> **Using the above example, I need to return "south" to a variable.**

Comment: `array_intersect` will not work how you are expecting with multidimensional arrays.

Comment: isnt "global" duplicated too?

Comment: @nickb ok, so can you assist me in what i *should* be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are looking for items that are in both arrays? ...

What about something like this:

```
function find_duplicate($array1, $array2)
{
  $list = array();

  foreach($array1 as $value1)
  {
    foreach($array2 as $value2)
    {
     if($value1 == $value2) $list[] = $value1;
    }
  }

  return $list;
}
```

Comment: This has more syntax errors than a script written by my cat jumping on the keyboard.

Comment: Still wrong. You are treating those arrays as one dimensional arrays, they are bi-dimensional.

Comment: @Jueecy: yes, I have to admit I haven't fully read the question, just quickly written the example ... but seems like it does work for Mark, if not, let me know I will update it ...

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to convert those arrays in arrays `array_intersect` can work with.
Considering:

```
$a; // first array
$b; // second array
```

then you would go with:

```
$a1 = array();
foreach ($a as $v) $a1[] = $v['slug'];

$b1 = array();
foreach ($b as $v) $b1[] = $v['slug'];

$c = array_intersect($a1, $b1);
```

PHP functions usually work with more powerful algorithms than what you may think; therefore it's a good choice to let PHP functions handle this kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to get at the values and takes the intersection of that

```
function mapper($a) 
{
    return $a['slug'];
}

$set1 = array_map('mapper', $post_cats);
$set2 = array_map('mapper', $ad_cats);
$result = array_intersect($set1, $set2);
```

[PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/j5j-6mf) for testing.